# Display authentication page on app built-in c# WebBrowser component when try to get UserCredential

Tags: c#, wpf, google-api-dotnet-client

I used the following code snippet to retrieve the `UserCredential` before.

```
UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(...);
```

It will launch default browser and display the authentication page when first authentication.

Now I want to add a `WebBrowser` component in my `WPF` application, and I would like to show the authentication page on my built-in `WebBrowser` component, but I can't find a way to implement it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by the Google .net client library at this time.  Currently GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync only opens a new browser there is no way to get the auth URI to embed it in your own webbrowser component.

There is an example of a windows phone UserControl [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.WP/OAuth2/WebAuthenticationBrokerUserControl.xaml) I have not tested it personally though. It might help

```
<UserControl x:Class="Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.WebAuthenticationBrokerUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:ClassModifier="internal"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <phone:WebBrowser Name="browser"
                          IsScriptEnabled="True"
                          Navigating="OnBrowserNavigating"
                          NavigationFailed="OnBrowserNavigationFailed"
                          Navigated="OnBrowserNavigated" />
        <ProgressBar Name="Loader" Height="10" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsIndeterminate="True" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The source code for the client library can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) it is an open source project so you are welcome to add it to the project.

there is also an issue request for this currently.   [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker in embedded browser?](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/547)